# NSMetadataQuery says there are no documents, despite data successfully syncing?

Tags: cocoa, nsnotifications, nsmetadataquery

I'm trying to get my OS X app to update automatically from changes to an iCloud document, and I'm having a really hard time getting the notification to work.  Specifically, I was given some code that should list out all the results of my `NSMetadataQuery` (just so I can do some testing and confirmation), but it's returning 0 results.  This, despite the fact that clearly something is there in my ubiquity container because the data is being uploaded from my OS X app successfully, and downloaded again successfully at launch.  Here's what I've got right now.

CloudDocument.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMetadataQuery *alertQuery;
```

CloudDocument.m:

```
@implementation CloudDocument

@synthesize alertQuery;

-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        alertQuery = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];
        if (alertQuery) {
            // Search the Documents subdirectory only.
            [alertQuery setSearchScopes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope]];

            // Add a predicate for finding the documents.
            NSString *filePattern = @"*";
            [alertQuery setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K LIKE %@", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey, filePattern]];
        }

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(queryDidUpdate:) name:NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(queryDidUpdate:) name:NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification object:nil];

        NSLog(@"Notification created");

        [alertQuery startQuery];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)queryDidUpdate:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [alertQuery disableUpdates];

    NSLog(@"Something changed!!! - %@", [notification name]);

    // Look at each element returned by the search
    // - note it returns the entire list each time this method is called, NOT just the changes
    int resultCount = (int)[alertQuery resultCount];
    NSLog(@"%i", resultCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < resultCount; i++) {
        NSMetadataItem *item = [alertQuery resultAtIndex:i];
        [self logAllCloudStorageKeysForMetadataItem:item];
    }

    [alertQuery enableUpdates];
}

- (void)logAllCloudStorageKeysForMetadataItem:(NSMetadataItem *)item {
    NSLog(@"LogAll gets called");
    NSNumber *isUbiquitous = [item valueForAttribute:NSMetadataItemIsUbiquitousKey];
    NSNumber *hasUnresolvedConflicts = [item valueForAttribute:NSMetadataUbiquitousItemHasUnresolvedConflictsKey];
    NSNumber *isDownloaded = [item valueForAttribute:NSMetadataUbiquitousItemIsDownloadedKey];
    NSNumber *isDownloading = [item valueForAttribute:NSMetadataUbiquitousItemIsDownloadingKey];
    NSNumber *isUploaded = [item valueForAttribute:NSMetadataUbiquitousItemIsUploadedKey];
    NSNumber *isUploading = [item valueForAttribute:NSMetadataUbiquitousItemIsUploadingKey];
    NSNumber *percentDownloaded = [item valueForAttribute:NSMetadataUbiquitousItemPercentDownloadedKey];
    NSNumber *percentUploaded = [item valueForAttribute:NSMetadataUbiquitousItemPercentUploadedKey];
    NSURL *url = [item valueForAttribute:NSMetadataItemURLKey];

    BOOL documentExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[url path]];

    NSLog(@"isUbiquitous:%@ hasUnresolvedConflicts:%@ isDownloaded:%@ isDownloading:%@ isUploaded:%@ isUploading:%@ %%downloaded:%@ %%uploaded:%@ documentExists:%i - %@", isUbiquitous, hasUnresolvedConflicts, isDownloaded, isDownloading, isUploaded, isUploading, percentDownloaded, percentUploaded, documentExists, url);
}

-(NSData *)dataOfType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError {
    [Data setSyncProgressIndicators:NO];
    return [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[Data getAllNotes]];
}

-(BOOL)readFromData:(NSData *)data ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError {
    [Data setSyncProgressIndicators:YES];
    NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary *)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:(NSData *)data];
    [Data didReceiveCloudData:dict];
    [Data setSyncProgressIndicators:NO];
    return YES;
}

+(BOOL)autosavesInPlace {
    return YES;
}

@end
```

The results that I'm seeing are that `queryDidUpdate:` gets called 2-3 times at launch, all from `NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification`.  Thing is, the "resultCount" variable is always 0, so `logAllCloudStorageKeysForMetadataItem` never gets called, and `NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification` never gets called at all, no matter how often I edit the cloud document.

Can anyone offer any advice about why the search is returning 0 results, despite the fact that there is clearly a file being synced back and forth?  Or even better, can you see what's wrong with the code entirely, and what I can do to get `NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification` on track and telling me when there have been edits to my file?  I am saving the file, btw, using the method:

```
+(NSURL *)notesURL {
    NSURL *url = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
    return [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:kAllNotes];
}
```

where "kAllNotes" = "notes".

Thank you in advance for your help!

**EDIT:**  Note that when I say it's syncing successfully, it's not doing it because of the NSMetadataQuery.  I've got a `cloudDoc = [[CloudDocument alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[self notesURL] ofType:NSPlainTextDocumentType error:nil];` line elsewhere that loads up the CloudDocument, so I know there's a document there and I know it's being changed by the iOS version of the app, but the NSMetadataQuery that I'm trying to master right now is only there to work with the `NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification`, and none of that seems to be working correctly.

Also, I am definitely a beginner, so code snippets and examples when making suggestions are very, very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found the answer: I've been saving my file to the root folder, but searching within `NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope`.  It should have been `NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDataScope`, and now it seems to be working perfectly.  I hope this helps people in the future!

Comment: If your app makes and saves documents, shouldn't you be saving them in your Documents folder (and looking for them in the corresponding scope)?

Comment: Oh, Peter. You and your insistence on "making sense." Yes, that would probably be a good idea...

Comment: Can you please give me a code snippet reference how to do following as I am new in document upload and download.

I want to achieve like whats app.

1) Upload document in iCloud custom folder
2) Track progress and show to the user
3) Upload successful inform user on 100% completion to iCloud 
4) Download document in iCloud custom folder
5) Download progress and show to the user
6) Download successful inform user on 100% completion to iCloud

Comment: Please note i am not doing real time iCloud document reference and like that , just like  whatsapp  to store the Zip for media files and Sqlite file that i will restore when the app is installed to another device.